# modifier only ibus keyboard layout switching in kde

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, kubuntu, keyboard-layout, ibus

I recently upgraded to kubuntu 14.04. I used to have <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> as a shortcut to change keyboard layouts back in 12.04 but its not working now. I see `<Shift><Meta>` as next input shortcut in ibus-setup but apparently its not working. I can assign other shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and it works fine.

I am aware that there was some issue with modifier only shortcuts, in unity however this seems to have been fixed in `gnome-settings-daemon` `3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11`. Indeed if I switch to Unity this shortcut works flawlessly but not in KDE.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is there another program that has the global Shift+Alt combination registered (System Settings > Common Appearance and Behavior > Shortcuts and Gestures > Global Keyboard Shortcuts)?

Comment: nope. in fact you cannot add shortcuts that are modifier only like alt+shift in Shortcuts and Gestures.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to **System Settings** -> **Hardware: Input Devices** -> **Keyboard** -> **Advanced** -> **Switching to another layout** and choose as you please, there are modifier-only and also normal shortcuts.

---

works with KDE Plasma 5